# Preventing href until gelocation captured (callback help)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After a user clicks an image (html code) I want it to ask for geolocation and only href when captured. The issue is that the specialDisplyLocation method is not being called at all to set the variables. I'm thinking it's something with the way I'm using the callback.

latlng, lat and lng are global variables

Here's the current code:

```
function getForSpecial(callback) {
    callback (arguments[1]);
}

function getGeo (compid){

    if (navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(specialDisplayLocation, displayError);
        window.location.href = "specials.php?cid="+compid+"&lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng;
    }else{
        display(2,"Sorry - your browser doesn't support geolocation! " +
            "Use your postal code.");
    }
}

function specialDisplayLocation() {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(position.coords.latitude),
        parseFloat(position.coords.longitude));
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    alert("lat: "+lat);
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="ad_125x125" 
    onclick="getForSpecial(getGeo,<?php echo $output125[0][0]; ?>)">
    <img src="/ed/img/promos/125/<?php echo $output125[0][1]; ?>" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are calling `specialDisplayLocation` as success callback. I would suggest you to redirect in that method.

```
function specialDisplayLocation() {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(position.coords.latitude),
            parseFloat(position.coords.longitude));
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    alert("lat: "+lat);

    //Redirect
    window.location.href = "specials.php?cid="+compid+"&lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng;
}
```

### EDIT

Try this

```
function getForSpecial(callback) {
    callback (arguments[1]);
}

function getGeo (compid){

    if (navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(){
            specialDisplayLocation();
            window.location.href = "specials.php?cid="+compid+"&lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng;
        }, displayError);

    }else{
        display(2,"Sorry - your browser doesn't support geolocation! " +
            "Use your postal code.");
    }
}

function specialDisplayLocation() {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(position.coords.latitude),
        parseFloat(position.coords.longitude));
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    alert("lat: "+lat);
}
```

Comment: Tried that. It still redirects over without prompting for geolocation. Comes over as: http://10.0.0.2/ed/specials.php?cid=7&lat=undefined&lng=undefined

Comment: It asked for location but still sent lat=undefined&lng=undefined to the new page. I guess it's something with those variables now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like it's not entering the specialDisplayLocation method. Adding () to the end fixed that.

Comment: @Denis, My bad, Use `specialDisplayLocation();` instead of `specialDisplayLocation;`. Updated answer

Comment: Now it doesn't href to the other page. Always something :P

Comment: @Denis, Are you getting alert. Don't worry we will get it done

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47128/discussion-between-satpal-and-denis)